# Returning a value from a function

Tags: python, return

I would like to know how to return

```
cardn
```

back into the

```
__init___
```

part of my program, where I can continue. This is in a class.

```
'''the dealing'''
    while card_count != 2:
        deal = random.randint(1,13)
        self.card_check(deal)
        print(cardn)
        card_count += 1




def card_check(self, card):
        if card == 1:
            cardn = "Ace"
        elif card == 11:
            cardn = "Jack"
        elif card == 12:
            cardn = "Queen"
        elif card == 13:
            cardn = "King"
        return cardn
```

All I want is the name of the card.

Comment: You don't need the right words, you need a basic [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions). The code should be `cardn = self.card_check(deal)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy! Just write

```
cardn = self.card_check(deal)
```

Comment: -_- :( Mind blank sorry. I flagged this question, so hopefully a moderator will take it down. Really stupid question :I

Answer (score 1):

In your case I see that others have responded with `cardn = self.card_check(deal)`, but `card_check()` does nothing with `self`. So it cold be just function. If it is method, then instead returning value you can set class member:

```
def card_check(self, card):
    if card == 1:
        self.cardn = "Ace"
    elif card == 11:
        self.cardn = "Jack"
    elif card == 12:
        self.cardn = "Queen"
    elif card == 13:
        self.cardn = "King"
    else
        self.cardn = str(card)
```

Notice that `cardn` is also set for other numbers, but you can check if it is integer between 2 and 10 and raise exception if not.

Also try to use Python tools like [pylint](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint). They show some warnings and should notice that `self` is not used in your method.

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions. You can create a list or hashtable mapping the card numbers to the card names.

```
def card_name(index):
    card_names = { 1: "Ace", 11: "Jack" }
    return card_names[index]
```

Your implementation of dealing (using randint) is not really proper. It makes the probability of each draw independent of previous draws. This is right for roulette, but not for blackjack. In blackjack you can run out of aces :-).

Comment: ah yes... i was just kinda messing around :) but i will certainly fix this and make sure that no repeat cards are added. Thankyou :0

Comment: @ReallyGoodPie The best way to go about it is to create a list of all the cards in the deck at the start of the program. Then each time you want to deal, create a copy of that list (`mycopy = list(mydeck)`), shuffle it using [`random.shuffle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle), and then deal cards by calling `mycopy.pop()`.

Comment: sweet, i love how you can start out with the most stupidest question and then get tonnes of tips and tricks do better your program ^_^ And learn 20 new things! this is why i love stack overflow :D

Answer (score 0):

Different way,

```
def card_check(x):
   return {
      1  : 'Ace',
      11 : 'Jack',
      12 : 'Queen',
      13 : 'King',
   }[x]


print card_check(1)
```

**Output**

```
Ace
```